# Function annotations

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

I really do like function annotations, because they make my code a lot clearer.
But I have a question: How do you annotate a function that takes another function as an argument? Or returns one?

```
def x(f: 'function') -> 'function':
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("{}({}) has been called".format(f.__name__, ", ".join([repr(i) for i in args] + ["{}={}".format(key, value) for key, value in kwargs])))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

And I don't want to do `Function = type(lambda: None)` to use it in annotations.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.5?

Comment: Yes I do. I like the new "async def" syntax. (minimum amount of characters in comments? Really?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the new [`typing` type hinting support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) added to Python 3.5; functions are *callables*, you don't need a function type, you want something that can be called:

```
from typing import Callable, Any

def x(f: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("{}({}) has been called".format(f.__name__, ", ".join([repr(i) for i in args] + ["{}={}".format(key, value) for key, value in kwargs])))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

The above specifies that your `x` takes a callable object that accepts any arguments, and it's return type is `Any`, e.g. anything goes, it is a generic callable object. `x` then returns something that is just as generic.

You could express this with `x(f: Callable) -> Callable:` too; a plain `Callable` is equivalent to `Callable[..., Any]`. Which one you pick is a style choice, I used the explicit option here as my personal preference.

Comment: What's better about this than simply annotating with `Callable`?

Comment: Thanks! I assume the last one is the type returned?

Comment: @CodingLambdas: it is.

Comment: @timgeb I think that it doesn't matter in this case, but does in other cases where the argument & return types are important. And since it is a good habit being consistent, I think this is the way to go, at least for me.

Comment: @timgeb: type inference tools can now make further assertions about anything using this decorator, an IDE can auto-complete based on the hints, etc.

Comment: @timgeb: in this *specific* case, a decorator has to accept a very generic callable and can't make any further assertions about that callable, but in most code, the assertions will be a lot more specific.

Comment: @timgeb: and yes, a plain `Callable` is equivalent to `Callable[..., Any]`. I just picked explicit over implicit here.

Comment: I was initially confused, but `...` is the `Ellipsis` object, of course.

Comment: Sadly PyCharm doesn't output anything if I am calling the function with wrong Arguments...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are the assertions done by using isinstance?

Comment: @CodingLambdas: PyCharm mostly uses type hints only for auto-completion and documentation. I guess type hint support there is still evolving. Have you looked at [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) at all?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Now I have. It seems pretty good, although an integration into an IDE would be nice.

Comment: @CodingLambdas: I don't know how PyCharm does their assertions, I don't use an IDE.

Comment: @CodingLambdas: type hinting is still very very new in Python 2. Tooling is still evolving.